# How can we heal HP while infected with Filth Fever?

Tags: dnd-4e

My party is trying get back to civilization alive (a city five days travel away), but we have two characters in the final stages of Filth Fever*: a 5th-level Paladin of Pelor and a 4th-level Rogue.

We also have a 3rd-level Artificer and a 2nd-level Wizard. What are our healing options?

Will any of these work?

1. Artificer's Healing infusion (since it doesn't use the target's healing surges)
2. Extended rest: can they still recover HP even if they don't recover any healing surges?
3. Potion of cure light wounds** (also doesn't require healing surges)

<sub>* They lose all healing surges and cannot regain hit points, and suffer –2 penalty to AC, Fortitude defense, and Reflex defense.

** From Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, none of those will work.**

The disease says they lose all healing surges *and cannot regain hit points*. They cannot be healed, *period*.

The closest you can get is temporary hit points, which are not the same thing as healing. Those wear off at the end of an encounter or after 5 minutes, though.

The *only* way they can be healed is by removing the disease with a successful Cure Disease ritual so they can heal normally.